# Avocado plant white resin/wax like substance on back of leaves. What could it be?

Tags: houseplants, diseases, avocado

I planted an avocado plant from seed about 2,5 years ago. The plant seemed to grow well, but I moved it alot, due to unproper conditions (lighting, temperature). For the last year, though, it stayed in my apartment and it began to look weak and develop some kind of white deposits on the back of its leaves.

[image: Avocado plant]
[image: Avocado leaf white deposits]

What could be the cause of this?

Edit: more pictures below.

[image: Back of leaf]
[image: Top of leaf]
[image: Another leaf]

Comment: Bogdan can you take a few more pictures, such as the top of the leaf.     I do not know what the white substance is, that is why I asked for a picture, but I do want to give you a pointer on taking care of you avocado.   Buy a grow light.  It does not need to be fancy.   A simple 100 W LED grow light will help your plant get through fall, winter and spring.  In summer it should be outside  or buy a stronger grow light.   Your apartment does not have the same light conditions as Mexico, where avocado are native.